# Can't find fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, fatal-error, null, optional-values

It was working last night, but when I run my code, now I am receiving a:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Can someone help me locate this error?

```
import UIKit
class UserRegistration: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

//USER REGISTRATION FORM

//Activity Indicator
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

//Error
func displayAlert(title:String, error:String){
    //create Alert
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//User Profile Picture Selection
var profileImage = UIImage()
var isThereImage = false
@IBOutlet var uploadProfilePictureButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func uploadProfilePicture(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Settings needed for image upload
    var image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary //can use '.camera' to access camera
    image.allowsEditing = true
    //Select image. FYI Completion is a function that happens when viewcontroller is presented
    self.presentViewController(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)  {
        //Store image in local variable to be resized later
        profileImage = image
        println("Image is selected")
        //Manually Close View Controller
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        //Remove button title
        uploadProfilePictureButton.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
        //Display Image
        uploadProfilePictureButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        //Set isThereImage Boolean
        isThereImage = true
    }

//---------------------------------------

//User Input Information
@IBOutlet var userEmailAddress: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var userPasswordOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var userPasswordTwo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordConfirmationMatch: UILabel!
var confirmedPassword = Bool()

//---------------------------------------

//Submit User Input to Database

@IBAction func userRegistration(sender: AnyObject) {
    var error = ""
    //Verify if User Exist and Passwords Match
    if userEmailAddress.text == "" || userPasswordOne.text == "" || confirmedPassword == false {
            error = "Please enter an email address and password, or make sure your passwords match."
            println("Registration had an error")
    }
    if error != "" {
        displayAlert("Error in Registration", error: error)
    } else {

    //Sign Up User
    var user = PFUser()

    //Resize Profile Picture
    let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(profileImage.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5))
    let hasAlpha = true
    let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
    profileImage.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //User Information
    user.password = userPasswordTwo.text
    user.email = userEmailAddress.text
    user.username = userEmailAddress.text
        if isThereImage == false {
            displayAlert("Please upload a picture for your profile.", error: error)
        }else if isThereImage == true {
            var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaledImage)
            var imageFile = PFFile(name: userEmailAddress.text + ".png", data:imageData)
            user.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "userProfileImage")
        }
    user.setObject("", forKey: "firstName")
    user.setObject("", forKey: "lastName")
    user.setObject("", forKey: "userLocation")

    //Insert Activity Indicator here
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    //-------------------------------

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool!, signupError: NSError!) -> Void in
            //Stop activity indicator whether there is an error or not
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            if signupError == nil {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            println("Registration Completed")
            } else {
                //Keep this here!
                if let errorString = signupError.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString{
                    error = errorString
                } else {
                    error = "Please try again later."
                }
            self.displayAlert("Could not Sign Up", error: error)
            println(signupError)
            }
        }
    }
    //Print Confirmation to Cortana
}

//---------------------------------------

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    passwordConfirmationMatch.hidden = true
    //UITextField Delegate
    self.userEmailAddress.delegate = self
    self.userPasswordOne.delegate = self
    self.userPasswordTwo.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Password Matching Function
func passwordCheck() {
    if userPasswordTwo.text == userPasswordOne.text {
        passwordConfirmationMatch.hidden = false
        confirmedPassword = true
        println("Password match")
    } else {
        passwordConfirmationMatch.hidden = true
        confirmedPassword = false
        println("Passwords don't match")
    }
}

//Handle Keyboard

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    passwordCheck()
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    userEmailAddress.resignFirstResponder()
    userPasswordOne.resignFirstResponder()
    userPasswordTwo.resignFirstResponder()
    passwordCheck()
    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: I believe it occurs at run time. I have 2 separate view controllers and want to connect one class file to both of them. Is that possible?

Comment: in what line does the error occur?

Comment: I am not sure of where to locate the line where the error occurs. I believe the error comes from a point in memory.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get indicates that one of your variables that has been declared as optional was nil when your code tried to access it.

Do you get any more info from the error? Like the name of the variable for example? If not, use some breakpoints to find the culprit and make sure it is not nil when the time to use it comes.

Comment: I'm going to try the breakpoints to find the culprit. Thank you!